# Missing something when converting rows to columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert rows to columns from a table, I was able to get the result set but for few records I am missing the logic. Below is the table and SQL I am running, if you the result of the query for P123 PROCEDURE_END should be NULL, Instead of NULL I am getting the PROCEDURE_BEGIN value. I am not sure what I am missing here, please help me out with this.

```
INSERT  INTO #PAT_TEST
VALUES  ( 'P123', 'D457', '2015-11-29 01:48:00.000', 1 )
,       ( 'P123', 'D457', NULL, 0 )
,       ( 'P872', 'D457', '2015-11-30 02:48:00.000', 1 )
,       ( 'P872', 'D457', '2015-11-30 03:48:00.000', 0 );

SELECT  PAT_ID
      , DOC_ID
      , PROCEDURE_BEGIN = MIN(PROC_TIME)
      , PROCEDURE_END = MAX(PROC_TIME)
FROM    ( SELECT    PAT_ID
                  , DOC_ID
                  , PROC_TIME
                  , rn = ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY PAT_ID, DOC_ID ORDER BY PROC_TIME ) - 1 ) / 2
          FROM      #PAT_TEST
        ) a
GROUP BY PAT_ID
      , DOC_ID
      , a.rn
ORDER BY PAT_ID
      , DOC_ID
      , PROCEDURE_BEGIN;
```

Comment: MIN and MAX functions don't operate on NULL values, they will simply ignore them and return the minimum and maximum dates from the remaining set. So, this is FAD as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you:

If null should be treated as the largest value:

```
SELECT PAT_ID ,DOC_ID, PROCEDURE_BEGIN=MIN(ISNULL(PROC_TIME,'99991231')), 
PROCEDURE_END=CASE WHEN MAX(ISNULL(PROC_TIME,'99991231')) ='99991231' THEN NULL ELSE MAX(ISNULL(PROC_TIME,'99991231')) END   
FROM( SELECT PAT_ID ,DOC_ID,PROC_TIME
,rn=(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PAT_ID,DOC_ID ORDER BY PROC_TIME)-1)/2
FROM #PAT_TEST
) a
GROUP BY PAT_ID ,DOC_ID, rn
ORDER BY PAT_ID,DOC_ID, PROCEDURE_BEGIN
```

[image]

If null should be treated as the Smallest value:

```
    SELECT PAT_ID ,DOC_ID, PROCEDURE_BEGIN=CASE WHEN MIN(ISNULL(PROC_TIME,0)) = '19000101' THEN NULL ELSE MIN(ISNULL(PROC_TIME,0)) END, 
PROCEDURE_END=MAX(PROC_TIME )   
FROM( SELECT PAT_ID ,DOC_ID,PROC_TIME
,rn=(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PAT_ID,DOC_ID ORDER BY PROC_TIME)-1)/2
FROM #PAT_TEST
) a
GROUP BY PAT_ID ,DOC_ID, rn
ORDER BY PAT_ID,DOC_ID, PROCEDURE_BEGIN
```

[image]